# Mount CD disk on mac as if it was mounted on windows

Tags: macos, partition, mount, optical-drive

Okay, the title is not really clear enough, but I can't think how to phrase it better.

So, the problem is, I have starcraft (1 and Brood Wars) CD that I'd like to play on mac 10.8 using Wine.

However, there's a difference when I insert the CD under mac os and under windows. On windows, there is setup.exe file, for example. On mac, I get different files (incompatible (classic) Starcraft Installer.app, some other folders) that don't exist when I insert the CD on windows

So, in short - CD has different files when mounted on windows, and when mounted on mac. I want to mount the 'windows' version of the starcraft cd on mac. How?

I tried making a cd image under windows (daemon tools lite), but when I mounted iso file, guess what, same thing happened.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you mount CD in mixed format that has separate files for Mac and for PC. You need to edit image with utility like Ultraiso/Toast to make it Win only.

For old Mac games I suggest you to using virtual machine with Mac version that can handle classic applications instead of running Wine port. (Actually this is not my idea, it is Apple's decision. After removing Rosetta this is all that we have)